# Django Rest Framework optional relation on serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add an optional relation field on my serializer which I use for create view like this:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    my_relation_field= PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=my_relation_field.objects.all())
```

But that gives me a strange error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'" even tho the id I pass is correct.

Comment: IT would be helpful to have more context such as the stack trace and what you were doing when you had the exception (get ? post ? what data and so on).

Comment: It seems that I was trying to use PrimaryKeyRelatedField when accessing parent from child. If I understand it correctly I should have used something like ForeignKeyField by there is no such thing. I think I will just use a workaround by passing an empty value to the serializer.

Comment: it is working? if that is not the case please add all related code please